# EF usage from thread spawned from Role.OnStart()

Tags: entity-framework, azure

I'm using EF code-first to manage my DB connection, with an explicit connection string declared in web.config. I would like to schedule some DB cleaning process (like deleting test transactions every day), so I'm spawning a thread from Role.OnStart() with proper concurrency management among the instances.

But I'm getting DB database exceptions, like the DB not matching my model, whereas I'm sure it does (the same code used from "inside" the app works well). So my guess is that web.config is not used from the thread, so EF probably uses the default connection string.

What would be the best way to use my connection string from there ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OnStart method doesn't run in the same process as your web application meaning it doesn't make use of the web.config. I suggest you store the connection string in the service configuration and read it from here when initializing your context.

An other advantage is that you change the setting without re-deploying the application.

Comment: Yep that's what I was currently implementing (calling the DbContext constructor in the custom DbContext constructor and passing the connectionString retrieved from RoleEnvironment makes it completely transparent for the rest of the app, btw). I was just wondering if there was a way to use web.config from the role process... Thanks.