# DbContext ASP.Net and Quartz.net

Tags: asp.net, azure, quartz.net, dbcontext

I just created a cron job like job using Quartz.net. For the test, it execute a simple request to the database. It simply adds a field.
I have a dbcontext:

> private TotoContext db = new TotoContext();

In my job I have:

> var totos = from u in db.totos where u.name == name select u;
>   Toto[] totoArray = totos.ToArray();

In my web.config, I have a special field with my specific connectionstring and so on ("TotoContext").
But when I create a new dbContext it seems that it uses doesn't use the good connectionString. In the watch the connectionString is not linked with "TotoContext".
I initialize my job in:

> public override bool OnStart()

And I have a specific Web.toto.config file with the connectionString for the build.

Why it doesn't use the good connectionString ?!

Thanks a lot !

**Edit:** if I set manually the connectionString in my db.Database.Connection.ConnectionString, it works. But why it doesn't use the web.config ConnectionString.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use full IIS mode (default configuration for web role), web.config will be ignored in the role entry point. So it is recommended to put all ASP.NET specific initialization tasks in Global.asax's Application_Start method. Role entry point is used to do something before ASP.NET application starts up, for example, modify IIS configuration. Inside Global.asax, web.config (and config transform) is respected.

Answer (score 0):

I just found why it's not using the Web.config: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10153375/1396323
But the next question is how to store different connectionString depending on the build config (Debug, Release etc...) and where ?